# How can I return current date as a 'String' in WSO2

Tags: javascript, wso2

I want to return current date as a String in WSO2. I already tried some methods but none of them works.

I parsed current date in my js file but could not change the type of it from integer to string in output.

```
var currentDateParse = mc.getProperty("currentDate");
```

How can I return `currentDateParse` as a string?

I expect the output of `currentDateParse` as a string like `"2019/05/29-22:42:00"`

Comment: Did you try `stringify()`? https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Comment: Yes, I tried stringify(currentDateParse) and It did not change the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use casting. Your answer would be `String(currentDateParse)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do as `currentDateParse.toString()`, It will work.

Comment: It works for js file but WSO2 does not accept it. String() worked actually, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via the SYSTEM_DATE property by defining the required format as below.

```
<property name="date" expression='get-property("SYSTEM_DATE", "yyyy-MM-dd&apos;T&apos;HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")' scope="default"/>
```

More: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Synapse+Message+Context+Properties